# Different plant compatibility and care

Tags: seeds, planting, germination, companion-planting

I've recently bought a few seeds: including that of Endive ( *Endivia Ruffec* ), lettuce, chicory, chard, cactus, and a flowering plant with the scientific name of *Viola Tricolor*.

Which plants have similar requirements and can grow in the same pot? And what are the general care guidelines for the " compatible batch "? (I'll ask a separate question for the plant(s) that aren't compatible) . Our weather is typically 50-60's F during winter , but we're on the verge of spring and the weather has been sunny with temperatures between 70-90F during daytime.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't grow any of them in the same pot - in the case of chicory, seedlings should be thinned out so that they are 12 inches apart (unless they're 'forcing' varieties, when its 6 inches apart), Chard, you'll get about 4 plants in a pot that's 12 inches deep and wide, for instance. Obviously, unless you're only going to grow one plant of each (and for leafy plants like lettuce and chard, that's not particularly useful) each one would do better in their own containers. Chicory needs a deep container (probably 10 to 12 inches), lettuce not so much, probably be fine in a container about 8 inches deep, though you've not said which variety of lettuce. Endive prefers a soil ph of 5 to 6.8 - one plant will need a 6 inch pot.

Viola tricolor is commonly known as pansy; you can either grow in a pot or in the garden, but I'd keep them separate to allow full development to your vegetable plants. Cactus, well, much better grown alone.

Comment: Hmm so I can't grow any alone, well that's a disappointment cause I only have three available pots. Though these general guidelines are helpful, I'm a complete newbie so I think I better ask separate questions for each, or can I ask about two or so in a question?

Comment: @user37026, not sure, sometimes the site's quite rigid about single questions only - I'd chance two at once, say lettuce and chard, see what happens! I thought you were a newbie to growing stuff - you might be wise to read up a bit about container veggie growing. You have to bear in mind that any plant is only as good as its roots, and each individual chard plant, for example, needs root room. I take it you have no space in the ground anywhere...

Comment: I do have a land section in my turtle's enclosure which I'm willing to plant, it's about 1m² in SA. Only problem is that I have sand in there not soil, so I might have to replace the sand if I plan to plant there.

Comment: not a huge space though you could put the chard in there - sounds like it might be easier to just go and buy the right size and number of containers.